# Ubuntu 12.04 - Wakes from Suspend by itself

Tags: 12.04, suspend

This problem has only just started and I don't know what has changed to cause it.

I suspend my ubuntu 12.04 PC and it used to stay asleep until I hit the enter key to wake it up but for the last week or so it's been waking itself up.

I've checked the BIOS settings and all the Wake on Lan settings are Disabled. I've used the ethtool command and the wake on lan is set to "d" which I've read been off.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: I had the same problem and went to turn off Wake on LAN settings. So your question is actually an answer to me! Thank you! I've been worrying that my laptop hard drive would be corrupted soon if ubuntu starts waking up while I'm moving about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it was an annoying one until I found the fix. I would suspsend my pc and then it would do so for like 3 seconds. After that, it just wake up automatically. I've found the fix here [Ubuntu Suspsend Fix.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290) Check out the post #6. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply -but I am a bit reluctant to try it as the description of the problem doesn't match to the problem that I have. My problem is that my ubuntu wakes itself from Sleep/Suspend. This is not mentioned in the link your provided.

Comment: oh nvm then... so yours wake up randomly some time after sleep/suspend... well good luck finding the fix... suspend problems in ubuntu happen a lot... if u hvn't tried it yet, i suggest trying it though. If that doesn't work, you just need to remove the file.

Comment: I didn't know that it was a simple action to reverse the change - so I'll have a go and report back. Thanks for your replies and sorry if my comments sounded negative.

Comment: I don't mind. :) and yes, your problem doesn't match the description in post #1. However, this seems to be like a general fix for suspend problem. I'm currently using the script from post #4. If that doesn't work, use the one from post #6.

Comment: I have now followed the instructions from post 4 and I'll let you know what happens tomorrow.

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thank you. One further question - now the computer will only wake when I press the power button - it used to wake by pressing any key on the keyboard - is this normal?

Comment: i don't need to press any key, i just open the lid. I think you need to check your pc's wake on keyboard, mouse etc settings and make sure they're enabled. Btw, glad it worked. :D