# Suspend problem

Tags: suspend

Recently, my laptop does not suspend though I saw it going into Suspend mode when I closed the lid of my Sony Vaio.  The PC just suspends for 1 second then lights on immediately. 
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go into screen settings
2. Make sure the "Lock Screen After:" setting is set to anything but "screen turns off"

   This option prevents the system from fully suspending

Answer (score 0):

Go to Power Settings via the task bar or System Settings and see what option you have for "When the lid is closed".

I have a Sony Vaio and it works fine for me. What series are you using and what release of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

[Suspend Fix for Laptop Using Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/224417/112005) Had same problem and fixed with this script. Seems like it is a common problem, not sure why they don't fix it.