# Suspend doesn't work (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: suspend

I'm new to Linux and to this forum, I recently purchased a DELL XPS-13 with Ubuntu 14.04.

Until now suspending my computer, either by closing the lid or clicking "suspend" in the menu did suspend my computer. I even sometimes had some problem waking it up, with the screen remaining black when I opened the lid. Now this issue seems to be fixed, but whenever I close the lid or click suspend, my laptop's screen remains lit, and just shows the login page, which, as you can imagine, has an impact on battery life.

I don't know why, but I can't get the screen to turn off when I close the lid or suspend.

I tried to run in Terminal

```
pm-suspend
```

and

```
pm-hibernate
```

but none seems to work at all, nothing happens.

I tried running the solution mentionned in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220715/ubuntu-12-04-wakes-from-suspend-by-itself/224417#224417) but nothing seems to work...

Any idea what might be the problem?

Thanks

---

Yes I wrote sudo before the command.
Here are the results of both commands:

```
adri@Adri-XPS-13:~$ sudo pm-suspend   
[sudo] password for adri: 
adri@Adri-XPS-13:~$ uname -r
3.16.0-37-generic
adri@Adri-XPS-13:~$
```

Comment: What kernel do you use. Give output of "uname -r"

Comment: The output is "3.13.0-52-generic"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP hasn't signed on in 18 months and problem has likely been resolved without the solution being posted.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395428/laptop-does-not-suspend-when-lid-is-closed

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to kernel 3.16, which is default in Ubuntu 14.04.2 and see if this problem has been fixed. To do it, run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

And reboot.

Comment: I did it, it didn't seem to change anythiing...

Comment: Do you do it with sudo, like "sudo pm-suspend"?

Comment: And give output of "uname -r" now